# is vector.into_iter().filter(some_non_trivial_function).collect() acceptable

Tags: rust

So if I have a `mut v: Vec<Foo>` and I want to maintain only the alive ones

I would do

```
v = v.into_iter().filter(|&foo| non_trivial_function_returning_a_result(foo).is_ok()).collect()
```

Will there be a new vector being allocated and then the original one destroyed?
What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios: Pointining to `retain` is appropriate (though an answer rather than a comment); the snark is really unnecessary :/

Comment: @MatthieuM. My intent wasn't to be snarky. When searching for a feature, it's better (self-formation) and even faster to have a lookup at the doc rather than asking online.

Comment: "I want to maintain only the alive ones" one element ?

Comment: Yes, I should have read the docs before asking but I am already done with my change and moved on to the next thing on my todo lists. I just thought maybe there is something in the code I just wrote that can be improved. So I posted my question, wrote another 300 lines of code and came back. Voila, the exact answer I am looking for (a slightly condescending comment? still worth it). Isn't that the whole point of stackoverflow?

"alive ones" -> [0, N] elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A new `Vec` will be allocated using the code you provided. There are a few possible ways to do this without allocations depending on your constraints (time-wise and stability)

**Vec.retain**
Pretty much the most easy way is to use [`Vec.retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain).

> Retains only the elements specified by the predicate.

You can use it like this:

```rust
let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
vec.retain(|&x| non_trivial_function_returning_a_result(x).is_ok());
assert_eq!(vec, [2, 4]);
```

**Vec.drain_filter**
If you want to do something with the removed elements that requires ownership, you can use the [`Vec.drain_filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain_filter) method. This method is only available in nightly rust at the time of writing.

You can use it like this:

```rust
#![feature(drain_filter)]

let mut numbers = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15];
for x in numbers.drain_filter(|x| non_trivial_function_returning_a_result(x).is_ok()) {
  // Do something with x
}
```

If you require ownership, but do not want to use nightly rust you can do it manually.

```rust
let mut i = 0;
while i != vec.len() {
    if non_trivial_function_returning_a_result(&vec[i]).is_ok() {
        let val = vec.remove(i);
        // do something with val
    } else {
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Parenthesis in `for` loop is an error: should be `for x in numbers.drain_filter(...) {}`.

Comment: @cyclaminist Thanks for the heads up, I edited the question. Althought it's a warning instead of an error, it shouldn't have those parenthesis.

Comment: Huh, I get an error, not a warning, for `for (x in 1..10) {}` in the playground.

Comment: Oh! You're right. If-statements generate warnings, but for-statements generate errors. I did not know that. I should check my facts before I say something like that, my apologies.